# jQuery disable input when another input has value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable specific input, when adding any text to another input. What tried doing is this
JS

```
$('#sPriceRewards').on('input', function() {
$(this).find('.inputReward').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="sPriceRewards" id="sPriceRewards" value="" />
<input type="text" name="sReward1" value="" class="inputReward" />
```

[Here's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teva/p623brhL/2/)

Tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple logic: https://jsfiddle.net/p623brhL/4/

```
$('#sPriceRewards').on('input', function() {

   if($(this).val().length)
      $('.inputReward').prop('disabled', true);
   else
      $('.inputReward').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the selector to target next element:

```
 $('#sPriceRewards').on('input', function() {
   $(this).next().prop('disabled', this.value.length);
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hfh7zq9/)**

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/p623brhL/3/ now works. You tried to find another input IN current one. But it is not child of current input

```
$('.inputReward').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sPriceRewards').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value.length > 0)
        $(this).siblings('.inputReward').attr('disabled','disabled');
    else
        $(this).siblings('.inputReward').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Please include some explanation of how this work or what you've fixed, rather than just code.